# SQLAlchemy Order By before Group By

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I've researched a lot in terms of doing a query to do an `order by` before a `group by` and have found most answers in terms of `raw SQL`. However, I'd like to see a solution in `SQLAlchemy Code`.

1. My original naive solution looked as follows:

   ```
   session.query(MyTable).order_by(timestamp).group_by(begin_date)
   ```

   > unfortunately, this causes the table to first be grouped then ordered, which will not return what I am expecting.
2. Second,I tried:

   ```
    stmt = session.query(MyTable).order_by(timestamp)
    session.query(stmt).group_by(begin_date)
   ```

   > This returns the correct results, however, the results are of `KeyedTuples` whereas I want to actually have MyTable objects for backwards compatibility reasons.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: With every database engine I've used, having order by before group by throws an error.  What answers did you find?

Comment: Can you show the SQL you're trying to produce?  do you maybe want `... group by begin_date order by begin_date, timestamp`?

Comment: I figured it out but can't post an answer to my own question, so here's the answer:

stmt = session.query(MyTable).order_by(timestamp);
session.query().add_entity(MyTable, alias=stmt).group_by(begin_date);

Answer (score 2):

The code in latest comment of original question seems still have some problem. Here is a working version:

```
stmt = session.query(MyTable).order_by(timestamp).subquery()
session.query().add_entity(MyTable, alias=stmt).group_by(begin_date);
```